# Maintaining staging+prod environments from single repo, 2 remotes with revel buildpack on heroku

Tags: heroku, staging, buildpack, revel

Revel models are defined under the `models` package; so in order to import them one must use the full repo path relative to the **%GOPATH/src** folder which in this case `project/app/models` thus results in

```
import PROJECTNAME/app/models
```

so far, so good i'f you'r using your app name as the folder name of your local dev machine and have dev+prod environments only.

[Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments) recommends using multiple apps for different environment (i.e. for staging). with the same repository with distinct origins;

This is where problem starts, now, since the staging enviromnent resides on alternative appname(let's say `PROJECTNAME_STAGING`), it's sources are stored under `PROJECTNAME_STAGING` but the actual code still `import PROJECTNAME/app/models` instead of `import PROJECTNAME_STAGING/app/models`; so compile fails, etc.

Is there any possibility to manage multiple environments with a single local repo and multiple origins with revel's heroku [buildpack](https://github.com/revel/heroku-buildpack-go-revel)? or a feature is needed in the buildpack that is yet to be implemented?

In addition, there is this possible issue with the `.godir` file that is required to be versioned and contain the git path to the app, so what about the multi-environment duality regarding this file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was simple enougth;
The buildpack uses the string in `.godir` **both** for the argument for `revel run` as well as the directory [name under](https://github.com/revel/heroku-buildpack-go-revel/blob/master/bin/compile#L68) `GOPATH/src`. My `.godir` file had a `git.heroku.com/<APPNAME>.git` format; Instead I just used `APPNAME` format.